# How do properly use queryset in a GenericAPIView in Django DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have started using GenericAPIView instead of APIView and I am confused about the use of queryset and serializer_class being defined at the top of the class.
I understand these have to be defined, but I now have a query at the top of my class and another query inside GET.  My question is can I use the queryset inside of my GET method so I am not making 2 unnecessary queries.

```
class demo(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Demo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DemoSerializer
    def get(self, request, num, format=None):
        query = Demo.objects.filter(name=test, number=num)
```

In other words, `queryset = Demo.objects.all()` is defined because it is required - but I am not really utilizing it so seems like an extra query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`queryset` required only in case you not defined [`get_queryset`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself) method. In your case instead of define additional queryset in `get`, just implement `get_queryset`. If you are using url's kwargs, you can get it inside this method with `self.kwargs` attribute:

```
class demo(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = DemoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Demo.objects.filter(name=test, number=self.kwargs['num'])
```

Comment: I just posted a stripped down version of my get method - there's a lot more logic in there.  I am now confused if just move all this functionality to get_queryset and remove get method completely - or split between the two.

Comment: @david it's better to split logic between two methods. Part related to queryset you can move to `get_queryset`. And inside `get()` just use `self.get_queryset()` .

Comment: can I define a base queryset inside get_queryset and then call queryset = self.get_queryset() inside get method and then apply further filters there?